# Powershell move files with timestamp in name into year/month folders

Tags: powershell, directory, batch-processing

I have a  lot of half-hourly files with names in the form `A_B_C_YYYYMMDDThhmm_YYYYMMDDThhnn.csv`
A, B and C are words
where `YYYY` is the year in 4 digits,
`MM` the month in 2 digits,
`DD` the day of the month in 2 digits,
`hh` the hour of the day in 2 dgits,
`mm` the minute in 2 digits,
and `nn` is mm+30 minutes

How can I move these files into folders based on years and months using Powershell?

I have made an attempt based on a previously used [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485727/move-files-into-year-month-folders-based-on-file-name-timestamp-powershell) but it is not producing any output for my filename format, presumably because the `match` string is wrong:

```
Push-Location 'path/to/files'
Get-ChildItem _*_*.csv |
  Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '_(\d{4})(\d{2})T(\d{4})_\d{6}T(\d{4})'} | ForEach-Object {
    $TargetDir = "{0}\{1}" -f $Matches[1],$Matches[2]
    if (!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){MD $TargetDir | Out-Null}
    $_ | Move -Destination $TargetDir 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, your regex pattern, as you presumed, was not matching your file names. I have changed the [pattern a bit](https://regex101.com/r/bWKI6d/1), and using [`[datetime]::ParsedExact(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider)) to extract the year and month. Haven't tested this previously but I believe it should work.

Needles to say, this code is not handling file collision, if there ever is a file with the same name as one of the files being moved to the destination this will fail.

```
Push-Location 'path/to/files'

Get-ChildItem -Filter _*_*.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.BaseName -match '(?:\w_){3}(\d{8})T\d{4}_\1T\d{4}') {
        $parsed = [datetime]::ParseExact(
            $Matches[1], 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
        )
        $folder = '{0:0000}\{1:00}' -f $parsed.Year, $parsed.Month
        $path = Join-Path $PWD.Path -ChildPath $folder
        if(-not (Test-Path $path)) {
            $null = New-Item $path -ItemType Directory
        }
        
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $path
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Santiago. This worked very well with some minor modifications

Comment: 1- I added the wildcard which I accidentally omitted in the original post (*_*_*.csv)
2 I replaced the \1T (matching most recent match) with (\d{8})T to account for transitions into the next day e.g. A_B_C_20200113T2330_20200114T0000
The online regex editor that you linked was also very helpful for testing.

Thanks again.